# When pandas will change the dtypes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I don't want to change the dtype of the Dataframe. The original dtype is:

```
id                             int64
symbol                         int64
period                         int64
start_at                       int64
open                         float64
high                         float64
low                          float64
close                        float64
volume                         int64
turnover                     float64
cross_seq                      int64
last_apply_1min_timestamp      int64
updated_at                    object
dtype: object
```

I use this code to change values in this Dataframe:

```py
for i in range(len(raw_sql_data_period_1)):
    temp_start_at_timestamp = raw_sql_data_period_1['start_at'].iloc[i]
    temp_data = raw_data[(raw_data['timestamp'] >= temp_start_at_timestamp*1e3) & (raw_data['timestamp'] <= (temp_start_at_timestamp+60)*1e3)]
    if len(temp_data) == 0 :
        continue
    open_price, high, low, close_price = GetOHIC(temp_data)
    raw_sql_data_period_1['open'].iloc[i] = open_price
    raw_sql_data_period_1['high'].iloc[i] = high
    raw_sql_data_period_1['low'].iloc[i] = low
    raw_sql_data_period_1['close'].iloc[i] = close_price
```

The outcome of `GetOHIC` are all `float64`. I only assign float64 value to this Dataframe, but after this loop, the dtype has been changed.

```
id                           float64
symbol                       float64
period                       float64
start_at                     float64
open                         float64
high                         float64
low                          float64
close                        float64
volume                       float64
turnover                     float64
cross_seq                    float64
last_apply_1min_timestamp    float64
updated_at                    object
dtype: object
```

My question is when ***Pandas*** will change the dtype? And why this will happen?

If I want to preserve the dtype, what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the shape of your dataframe has changed after the loop. Some `NaN` rows/values has in fact appeared in your `int64` columns and that's probably why pandas converted those to `float64`. Read this : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#integer-dtypes-and-missing-data

Comment: @abokey Thanks! Yes I found it kinda weird. The length of the origin dataframe is 93. And I apply a filter to get a new dataframe whose length is 59. But I try to print out the index when I use `iterrows`, it becomes 93 again. I can confirm I use the new dataframe. So that's why there are some value with the float64